# How to upload images and videos to my server in facebook application

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

how to upload images and videos to my server in facebook application. if i use 
file tag facebook strips all file tags before sending in a request. iframe is the only way to upload images and videos?
 please help me...

Comment: You answered your own question, Mark it an answer.

Comment: @stefan i just want to know whether iframe is the only way to upload? is there any graph api something like that which facebook provides

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded with Static html iframe tabs - http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196  which makes life so easy to manage tabs, embed video and direct pages as well. This is not the direct answer but a definite viable alternative.